# Android Studio - GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

The wierd thing is I have a working example but in a new project I'm getting this error message.

What I have tried:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
}

dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"
}
```

And I ensure I have sdk installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved by myself:

First of all, I updated the gradle plugin.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```

Then just Build->Clean project and everything works again.